# Why do sounds reset in cubase after loop returns?

Tags: midi, cubase

I've got a Nord Modular and a Roland Juno 106 and a TR909 wired with Cubase that sound good until the loop returns, then the Nord Modular and the Juno switch sounds to the default sounds. Why is this happening and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Is there an answer on this question? I've the same problem and can't find it out..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is half guess and half intuition: -

Maybe the default midi settings for the cubase track need to be set correctly so that when the loop goes back to the start, cubase doesn't issue default midi instrument settings?

If you set start and end loop points within the extents of the track does it loop and keep the same settings OK?

Comment: No it doesn't always keep the setting. I checked the settings in Cubase and it has not any special setting. The patch should not reset but it does. Where is the setting? All I could find in file...proferences was settings for MIDI reset on restart and there was no setting for the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my guess:

The problem is that the default zero PC/CC values are transmitted at loop start, and whatever state your machines are in lost.

The quick fix is to stop Cubase from sending these messages. You can use the List Editor to find these and delete the messages.

Depending on your Cubase version, you may have the Logical Editor or Logical Presets (MIDI->Logical Presets->standard set 2->del patch changes).

But even better: try to record/specify the real program change and controller change messages. This way you will be able to use more than one setting per device per song (with you having to stop, reconfigure and bounce another part).